# NgbTooltip not showing the arrow div ( ▼ ) inside NgbPopover Window

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

It seems that the arrow div doesn't work inside NgpPopover body because of conflicting arrow classes for NgbPopover's div.arrow and NgbTooltip's div.arrow. Looks like this is a [problem in ng-bootstrap with bootstrap v4](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/4140) but can be resolved by updating to the new bootstrap v5.

However, If we can get a workaround for this then it will be very convenient for teams to get this issue fixed temporarily.

See the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfekrd?file=src/app/popover-triggers.html) to recreate this issue.

**Versions:**

```json
{
   "@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
   "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.1",
   "bootstrap": "^4.6.0"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to upgrade, as a workaround you can define a custom `tooltipClass` for your tooltip:

```
<ng-template #popoverContent>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <button ngbTooltip="Tooltip with missing arrow " tooltipClass="my-custom-class" [closeDelay]="2000000"> Button inside Popover Window</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

and in the CSS you can define this which will override the transparent `border-color` that is being applied by the popover CSS:

```
::ng-deep .my-custom-class .arrow::before {
  border-top-color: black;
}
```

[image]

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfekrd-xidipn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpopover-triggers.html) for a demo.